Testing Renovate config by running it locally using npx not working
I would like to run Renovate locally, like described in the docs.
I can run the following test project with the 2 files (package.json and renovate.json) without any problems using the Mend-hosted app (GitHub App Renovate Bot).


But when I try to run it locally from within the repository using
LOG_LEVEL=debug npx renovate --platform=local --repository-cache=reset
I get the following error. I have npm installed using the apt package manager.
/home/$USER/.npm/_npx/05eeecd92f4e18e0/node_modules/renovate/dist/instrumentation/index.js:33
            [semantic_conventions_1.ATTR_SERVICE_NAME]: process.env.OTEL_SERVICE_NAME ?? 'renovate',
                                                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gautam/.npm/_npx/05eeecd92f4e18e0/node_modules/renovate/lib/renovate.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

package.json:
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "5.2.0"
  }
}

renovate.json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ]
} 


facing similar error, managed to solve it before not sure what i did. Facing similar right now

are you creating custom image or so ? higher chances it might be running the older Node version i solved it upgrading the version.

Hey thanks. Since I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed Node from the apt repositories, a much older version (v12.22.9) was installed. Now I have v20.18.0 installed and it works without any problems.

That's really great to hear, i am too running the 22 node now & latest renovate so yes so far going good.

As @Harsh-Manvar mentioned the problem lied in the old version of node installed using apt on Ubuntu 22.04. I installed a more up to date version, specifically v20.18.0, and it worked.
